# Linux SQL Server: can't show logs with SSMS

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu-16.04

Just installed SQLServer (Express edition, ver. 14.0.3030) on Ubuntu 16.04.3.

Usual operations work without errors: client connections and queries, AD integrated logins, backup/restores.

I can't show logs with SSMS (ver. 17.8.1) from Windows 10 Pro 1709 x64: expanding "Management" --> "SQL Server Logs" I get the following error:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------
Failed to retrieve data for this request.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476
------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
(Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
------------------------------
A severe error occurred on the current command.
The results, if any, should be discarded. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 0)
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=14.00.3030&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=0&LinkId=20476
```

A search on Google lead to posts that suggested to run sys.xp_readerrorlog.
Here's the output:

```
EXEC sys.xp_readerrorlog

Msg 22004, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Failed to open loopback connection. Please see event log for more information.
Msg 22004, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Error log location not found.
```

SQLServer logs in `/var/opt/mssql/log` show nothing interesting.
Any suggestion?

**UPDATE**: tried connecting both with SQL authentication and Integrated AD authentication: same error.

Comment: The `SSMS` is running on windows, and the `SQL Server` on Ubuntu, right?

Comment: Yes, right. I've just added this info to the question.

Comment: As you are using the latest version I thing it will be better to submit a bug - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=sqltools

Comment: I have no problems reading Ubuntu logs using SSMS V17.8.1 with SQL authentication on Windows 10. Are you using SQL authentication or AD integrated?

Comment: @gotqn: will post there, thanks ;)

Comment: @DanGuzman: yes, tried with both auth methods with the same result.